# FLUTTER API: can't use ".body"

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I can't use ".body" , even if im trying to just "print(result.body);"

Im getting this error message:
[image: Error i get]

```html
String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments";

    var result = http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    apiList = jsonDecode(result.body)
```

I have no idea how to fix, any help is welcomed.
If you need aditional information, im ready to provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your function `async`, then

```
var result = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: Thanks, you made it look easy. Where I can find more documentation about API's in flutter? (actual version)

Comment: your welcome

[http](https://pub.dev/packages/http)
or
[dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

Comment: Look at the async codelab as well: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await